# Показать часть текста по клику

Tags: html, jquery, css

Помогите выдвинуть весь текст по клику!
Кликая правой кнопкой по тексту видно то что должно всплыть при нажатии на стрелочки, но не могу понятьк как это сделать!
http://new.teplo-comfort.ru/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если вы используется bootstrap - все уже сделано для таких вещей -
 https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp

Comment: Использую, а на русском есть что-то?

Comment: http://bootstrap-3.ru/javascript.php#collapse

Comment: Ну аналогичные уроки даже есть в ютубе а толку если там все скрыто и по кнопке? у меня же часть текста открыта, типичный спойлер я и так могу сделать но тут не весь текст скрыт а половина

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/d66h1b4c/

Comment: судя по всему проблем исчерпана?

Comment: Сделал как в примере soledar10 , но по клику по button просто кидает в начало страницы...

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, fidle немного отличается просто но справился